Alternative to the lxpolkit authentification agent
I'm currently using lxpolkit on my i3-wm setup, and am curious about one aspect.
I use the 1password manager, which prompts me to unlock it using lxpolkit. The window is pretty ugly though, and the biometric is an additional second popup, that doesn't react or disappear on a successful login. I have to guess if I did it correctly and press enter.
Is there a way to change this or use an alternative with better customizability or default better looks?
Thanks
